# How to extract int128 from msg.data as first argument?

Tags: bytes, payable

Let's say we have Ethereum smart contract with fallback function:

```
event onDeposit(int128 indexed key, address from, uint amount);
... 
function () payable public {
  require(msg.value > 0);

  int128 key = ... // how to extract it from msg.data? (0x123)
  address from = msg.sender;
  uint amount = msg.value;

  // fire event
  emit onDeposit(key, from, amount);
}
```

and taking into account `key` is entered in myetherwallet.com like that:

[image]

Is it correct that i should skip 4 first bytes in `msg.data` (function address) and get the next 4 bytes (int128 size)? How can i do it (slice bytes and cast them as int128)?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it correct that i should skip 4 first bytes in msg.data (function address)

No, because no function selector is being included in the data.

> and get the next 4 bytes (int128 size)?

An `int128` is 16 bytes wide (128 bits).

I believe just doing `int128(msg.data)` will work, assuming the data is properly formatted (16 bytes wide, left-padded with zeros).

Comment: oh, yes, 16x8=128. When function selector is included and not?

Comment: It's up to the client what they include in the `data` field, but here you seem to be typing it in by hand. So unless you've encoded a function selector, there isn't one.

Comment: so it's just any bytes array without any structure/markup?

Comment: Yeah, the structure (ABI encoding) is done by the client (e.g. web3.js) and then parsed by the smart contract.

Comment: thanks. it's not related question, but can i set `msg.data` with Remix? I did not find how to do it

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do that directly. But you could make your own contract that does it: `function foo(bytes data) { address(<target contract address>).call(data); }`

Comment: `int128(msg.data)` does not work: `TypeError: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "bytes calldata" to "int128"`